# Meaning of 「緊張しながら」 and grammar of 「〜しながら」 part

Tags: grammar, usage, meaning, nuances

Could you explain more precisely the meaning and grammar of 「緊張しながら」? I know that 「緊張」 means "nervous" or "tension", but 「〜しながら」 - I can't understand this part.

Comment: Could you please supply the entire sentence?  Also, could you tell us what you've done to try to solve your problem so far?  For example, have you looked up ながら in a dictionary?

Comment: I can not remember the entire sentence, because I heard it on TV so quick. The main goal of this question was to understand the grammar of 「〜しながら」 part. On Google total absurd about this phrase, on [ALC](http://eow.alc.co.jp/search?q=%E7%B7%8A%E5%BC%B5%E3%81%97%E3%81%AA%E3%81%8C%E3%82%89) - just one example..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

「〜しながら」literally translates to "while {verb}~ing}. The form is basically basic verb+ながら "i.e. "緊張し+ながら". So in your example, it basically means "While worrying....."

Comment: Just I little information: 〜しながら splits into し + ながら, where し is 連用形 (continuative) form of する.